# CPU Usage in Linux. in C - compiler problems

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

I've been trying to read and print in terminal all my CPU cores usage.
My program work fine until I've made it a multithread app, and now my compiler seams to say that there is no reference betwin source codes, even thou I can't find what's the problem.
This my header file:

```
#include <pthread.h>

extern int cpu_user[16];
extern int cpu_sum[16];
extern float cpu_proc[16];

extern pthread_t t_reader;
extern pthread_t t_analyzer;
extern pthread_t t_printer;

extern pthread_mutex_t mutex_r;
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex_a;
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex_p;

void *reader();
void *analyzer();
void *printer();
//void *logger();
//void *watchdog();
```

My main source code, with main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "funkctions.h"

void closing();

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, closing);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_r, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_a, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_p, NULL);

    pthread_create(&t_reader, NULL, reader, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t_analyzer, NULL, analyzer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t_printer, NULL, printer, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void closing(){
    printf("\nCleaning and closing...\n");

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_r);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_a);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_p);

    pthread_join(t_reader, NULL);
    pthread_join(t_analyzer, NULL);
    pthread_join(t_printer, NULL);

    printf("\nDONE!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

My reader function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "../funkctions.h"

int cpu_user[16];
int cpu_sum[16];

void *reader(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_r);
        char buffer[255];

        FILE *pFile;
        pFile = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pFile); //discarding 1st line of /proc/stat

        for(int i = 0; i < 16 ; i++){ //reading lines form 2 do 17 (for 16 cpu cores)
            int temp = 0;  //setting temp to zero for every for loop
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pFile); //reading next line of /proc/stat        
            sscanf(buffer, "%*s %d", &cpu_user[i]); //saving 2nd line of /proc/stat ---> to extern int array
            char *token = strtok(buffer, " "); //setting token for new buffer
            while(token != NULL){   //token in NULL when there is nothing more in string to process
                if (sscanf(token, "%d", &temp) == 1){ //finding next decimal (sscanf returns 1 when it finds a match)
                    cpu_sum[i] += temp; //sum of cpu usage for every core ---> to extern int array
                }
            token = strtok(NULL, " "); //going to next part of string when token found
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_r);
        }

        fclose(pFile);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

My analyzer function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#include "../funkctions.h"

float cpu_proc[16];

void *analyzer(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_a);
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            cpu_proc[i] = ((float)cpu_user[i]/(float)cpu_sum[i])*100;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_a);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Printer function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "../funkctions.h"

void *printer(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_p);
        printf("\n------------------------------");
        for(int i = 0; i < 16 ; i++){
            printf("\nCPU%d: %7.2lf%%", i, cpu_proc[i]);
        }
        printf("\n------------------------------");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_p);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

And compiling command with response:

```
gcc -o main main.c functions_source/analyzer.c functions_source/printer.c functions_source/reader.c -lpthread


/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6dGjI5.o: warning: relocation against `t_printer' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6dGjI5.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `mutex_r'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `mutex_a'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `mutex_p'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `t_reader'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `t_analyzer'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `t_printer'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6dGjI5.o: in function `closing':
main.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `mutex_r'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `mutex_a'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `mutex_p'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `t_reader'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `t_analyzer'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `t_printer'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccH46vwi.o: in function `analyzer':
analyzer.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `mutex_a'
/usr/bin/ld: analyzer.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `mutex_a'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDXHFL5.o: in function `printer':
printer.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `mutex_p'
/usr/bin/ld: printer.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `mutex_p'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccREn7jd.o: in function `reader':
reader.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `mutex_r'
/usr/bin/ld: reader.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `mutex_r'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've been trying to relocate declaretions and intializations of mutexes and threads but nothing seems to work. I was trying to move them to main.c and other files.
Also looked for some misspelling but also cant find any.
I would like this code to have 3 working thread that would sleep for 1 s after every loop and for it to be terminated by Ctrl+C signal.

Answer (score 1):

You do not define them in any ***`C`*** source file. `extern` declarations in header files do not define them magically.

In one of the `C` filers you need to add definitions of those variables

```
 pthread_t t_reader;
 pthread_t t_analyzer;
 pthread_t t_printer;

 pthread_mutex_t mutex_r;
 pthread_mutex_t mutex_a;
 pthread_mutex_t mutex_p;
```

Comment: Why was I DV-ted for the correct answer?